# How to convert html string to html elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working in a form builder application. The user creates a form and the form is saved into database.
when the user clicks on the form name from a list of forms, the form data must be selected from database including the source code of the form, the source code is a string. Is there a way to convert the string as html form ?

I tried this

```
   var win = window.open("about:blank");

   win.document.write(userText);
```

but the new window

```
  <legend>Form builder demo</legend>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <div class="row-fluid" id="form-title-div">
        <label>Type form title here...</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use innerHTML : [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create object of form

```
Set formob = document.YourformName
```

and then use

```
document.write(formob.userText.value)
```